# This is the same thing as SleekEZ that is already on the market or not?

Tags: prior-art-request, claims

In reference to the patent: [US20150047576](https://www.google.com/patents/US20150047576)

From this application's claims,

> What is claimed is:
>
> 1. A grooming tool comprising: a blade; a solid wooden handle; wherein said blade is contained within a wooden handle.
>
>    2. The grooming tool of claim 1 further comprising: bi-metal blade, wherein said blade is pressure fitted into a slot in the wooden handle.
>    3. The invention of claim 2 wherein a rubber blade is permanently attached to said wooden handle by insertion of epoxy into said slot in said wooden handle.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Patents! I've edited your post to include the claims from the application you cited. If possible, do you think you could add in a bit of information about SleekEZ, and how you think it relates to the claims I quoted? That will help our community answer your question more quickly.

Comment: Well, other than the rubber, the rest of the claims are so broad it could be anything almost already on market.  Prior art is sold in stores all over the country and worldwide, has been in a number of well-known magazines in front of millions of readers, etc.  While I do not believe patent would ever be granted on the above as it is written, this applicant intentionally filed this application knowing that the prior art existed.  We requested non-publication for our reasons. Despite our product clearly stating PATENT PENDING, the applicant parrots our every word for her product.